# how to receive the offline SMS in android programatially

Tags: android, sms, offline-mode

If my android device is switched off , at that time some one is sending sms to my mobile.
once I switch on I want to get the SMS through programatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch SMS from Inbox like this:

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                                    "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
            Log.e("Count",count);
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
                String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi .. I dont want to read from the inbox. I have done the below things already.
1.I am blocking the sms using the Abortbroadcast. So when ever sms is received it will come to my receiver.
2. I can able to get the sms when my device is online.
3.If i switched off my mobile how i wil get the sms by using my Broad casrt receiver.?????

Comment: I cross checked it over my device. When your device is switched on your device will receive the sms sent when device was switched off, your receiver should get it's notification...

Comment: @VineetShukla Do you know how to count the number of messages in the inbox and also count the number of messages per contact?